# populate a list of cells depending on a certain cell value in excel

Tags: excel, validation

so I have a table in Excel that lists a mixture of animal feed depending on their age, what I'd like to do is to make a calculator in which I will enter a feed component and the amount that I have and automatically the calculator will figure out what other component is needed and how much do I add to the mixture.

The table looks similar to this, where there are two lists, "Cycle" and "Feed", "Feed" list value changes depending on which "Cycle" we are in, [image][image]

After I select the "Feed" and entered the amount, the "Other mixture components" cells below it should be populated with the rest of the values in the "Feed" list and their corresponding amount.

A sample of how it would look like when I select "Starter" for the Cycle and "Rice Bran" for the Feed

[image]

Comment: So you need a table with the amounts stated for each cycle, then use index() with match() to get the correct result from the table.

Comment: Either you can use name manager or `Filter()` function if you are on ***Microsoft 365***.

Comment: Sadly, I do not have Microsoft 365, mine is 2019. I checked and Filter() would have solved my problem, anyway, what I did was to manually put if() function on each cell, and seem to be working just fine for such small number of cells, only needed 6 cells populated at most. Of course, this would never work if i had to deal with hundreds of cells.

Comment: @Don Do you have those values of Mixture Components in other sheet referencing each to Cycle & Feed respectively, if so then its possible without `FILTER()` Function as well, you dnont have to use `IF()` there are other functions which are dynamic and robust. For this i need to see the data properly to create the formula. Let me know please